# wpf user authorization and authentication

Tags: wpf, authentication, authorization

In my application I need to control who can read and write in the different GUI elements. The users will have a role. But how can I set the authorization on the different elements to check if the user is authorized to write or not?
Are there any good examples around?

Answer (score 1):

See class [WindowsIdentity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.aspx). It shows you all user data.

If you use MS AD, I recommend you to use Domain level 2003+, to get more data from this class.

Comment: I'm not going to use Windows authentication so this will not be the solution for me. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [UIAuth](http://uiauth.codeplex.com/) It's an infrastructure that allow you to control authorization base on VM properties. with behaviors.